# What is the use of the 'Parameters' tab in the script record?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a scheduled script (running from a Suitelet script) that is getting parameters from a Suitelet. What do the parameters in the Parameter tab do?

[image]

my suitelet code chunk:

```
var params = [];
params['custscript_emp_accrual'] = empreq_id;
params['custscript_emp_months'] = rowCount;
nlapiLogExecution('debug', 'empreq_id:rowCount', empreq_id + ':' + rowCount);
nlapiScheduleScript('customscript_emp_accrual_sched', 'customdeploy_emp_accrual_sched', params);
```

my scheduled code chunk:

```
var empreq_Id = nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT', 'custscript_emp_accrual');
var month = nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT', 'custscript_emp_months');
var dateNow = nlapiLookupField('customrecord_payroll_period', month, 'custrecord_payperiod_enddate');
```

Answer (score 2):

They're ways to setup script deployments. Check out the help doc "Creating Script Parameters Overview" for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to focus your learning on SuiteScript 2.0, this is most widely used in industry and has more support online.

Script parameters are very useful for variables that could either change over time or be different between script deployments.

This is just a simple example of how you could use parameters:
You could have a script that could be deployed to more than one record type and on each record type you certain code to be executed for a different user.
Now you can add a script parameter called USER, which is a select/multi-select field. This means that on each script deployment, you can specify a different user for which your code should run.

Now you could have the following code to read your parameter and restrict editing:

```
var allowedUser= runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter('custscript_user');
var currentUser= runtime.getCurrentUser();
if(currentUser == allowedUser){
     //do something
}
```

You can now select a different user on each of your script deployments.

Hope this helps!

For more info, have a look at page 110 of this document from Oracle: [SuiteScript Developer Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSCDG/NSCDG.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The Parameters allow you to pass data from the Suitelet to the Scheduled Script. If you don't set up the script parameters then the data won't be passed to the Scheduled Script.